# (GNU Octave/MATLAB)'x' is specified as variables of equations, but keep saying x is not specified

Tags: matlab, octave

'x' is specified as @(x), but error message keeps coming up.

```
    <i> function F = drawCFRPgraph0726(X, y, E, I, A, G, r, c, m)
    t(1) = pi/2+0.0000001;
    i = 1;
     while t(i)<pi
     disp(t(i));
     for k = 1:500
     L(k) = 0.000001*k;
     dvdx(x) = @(x) ((x/3-L(k)/2)(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))+x*       (L(k)/2-x/3)(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))^2+x(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(3*(x-L(k)))+x*(y-t(i)+pi/2)*(x/3-L(k)/2)/(x-L)+x*t(i)-x*y-pi*x/2)/L(k);
     d2vdx2(x) = @(x) ((-2*x/3+L(k))*(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x*(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))^2+x*(2*x/3-L(k))*(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))^3-2*x*(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x*(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(3(x-L(k))^2)+2*(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x*(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(3*(x-L(k)))+(y-t(i)+pi/2)*(2*x/3-L(k))/(x-L(k))+x*(-2*x/3+L(k))*(y-t(i)+pi/2)/(x-L(k))^2+2*x*(y-t(i)+1.5708)/(3*(x-L(k)))+t(i)-y-pi/2)^2/L(k)^2;
     A(k) = quad(dvdx(x), 0, L(k));
     B(k) = quad(dv2dx2(x), 0, L(k));</i>
```

Comment: Consider accepting hte answer if it helped

Answer (score 5):

you are wrongly defining the anonymous function.

To define them properly you should:

```
dvdx = @(x) ((x/3-L(k)/2)(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))+x*       (L(k)/2-x/3)(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(x-L(k))^2+x(c*L(k)*m/(c+r)-x(t(i)-y-pi/2))/(3*(x-L(k)))+x*(y-t(i)+pi/2)*(x/3-L(k)/2)/(x-L)+x*t(i)-x*y-pi*x/2)/L(k);
```

This means: now `dvdx` is a function that takes 1 argument (`@(x)`) and evaluates it with the following equation `((x/2-L(k) ...`. But `x` is not defined outside, the same way `X, y, E, I, A, G, r, c, m` are not defined outside, just inside the function.

The first input of `quad` is a function, and the function is not `dvdx(x)` but just `dvdx`

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Not sure about octave. In MATLAB the definition is wrong. Try `a(x)=@(x)(x.^2)` and `a=@(x)(x.^2)`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I hadn't even seen those three characters.